# Laravel 9: testing get profile (by slug) for created row

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I wrote test:

```
public function test_hello_world(){
    $test = User::create(['name' => 'Test',
        'email' => 'test@test.com',
        'password' => 'password',
    ]);
    Profile::create([
        'user_id' => $test->id,
        'name' => 'Test',
        'slug' => 'test'
    ]);

    $this->get('/profile/test')
        ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

What this code should testing? After get to this url it should display details about profile. If profile with this slug doesn't exist, we have error 404. In this test I create user and profile table (this 2 tables is connection) but after run test I have the error:

> Expected response status code [200] but received 404.   Failed
> asserting that 200 is identical to 404.

Why I have this error since I created profile with this slug? For me the best option will be create testing database with a lot of records and conduct all test on it. Is it possible? How do that?

@Edit

I have a route and controller's method which display user's profile. If I go (in web browser) to localhost/profile/slug, it works, if this profile exist. My controller's method look like this:

```
public function show($slug) {
    $profile = Profile::where('slug', $slug)
                      ->firstOrFail();

    return Inertia::render('Profile/Single', [
        'profile' => $profile,
    ]);
}
```

And route:

```
Route::get('/profile/{slug}',
           [ProfileController::class, 'show'])
           ->name('profile.show');
```

Comment: Can you show your routes file, as well as the controller function for that route?

Comment: Well it's getting a 404 in response. Since this snippet of code looks fine. What is the logic behind doing a get request to `/profile/test`? As in show us `routes.php` and the controller function for `/profile/test`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement you have to create route for getting profile from slug name. You did wrong in single function. Without creating route it will not worked.

So below example may work for you.

For example:-

**For creating data**

```
public function createData(){

  $user = User::create(['name' => 'Test',
   'email' => 'test@test.com',
   'password' => 'password',
  ]);

  Profile::create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'name' => 'Test',
    'slug' => 'test'
  ]);

  return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data created');
}
```

**For Getting Data**

```
public function getDataBySlug($slug){
   $profile = Profile::where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail();

   return redirect('/dashboard')->with('slug', $slug);
}
```

**In route file**
you have to mention table name and column name {profile:slug} instead of id

```
Route::get('/profile/create', 'Controller@createData');
Route::get('/profile/{profile:slug}', 'Controller@getDataBySlug');
```

Your route definition is wrong please do as above

Comment: While this in itself is a great answer, there are a lot of assumptions done. For example, since the original question is missing some key information (what is the controller function for the `/profile/test` route, has OP set the routes up properly), we aren't certain that the asker has these controller methods and these routes..

Comment: You have to pass table name in your slug route as i mentioned in above answer. 
Please check route from above answer how to add table name and column name for slug

Comment: When you want to use other field rather than id in route. The. You have to mentioned table name and column name other wise it will give you 404 error. 
{profile:slug} In this exmple profile is your table name and slug is your column name

Comment: I changed that `Route::get('/profile/{profile:slug}',
           [ProfileController::class, 'show'])->name('profile.show');` but efect is this same.

Comment: whats's your profile table  name?

Comment: You sure. My table's name is profiles. I change that but it doesn't solve my problem. All the time I have this same error.

Comment: Curiosity - I tried change slug to id (of course I changed query in controller and argument of controller's method) but effect is this same.